# How to check Google+ Hangout ending event using the API

Tags: ajax, google-plus, google-hangouts

I have been working on a web app that, among other things, allows users to communicate with each other using Google+ Hangout.

The web app initiates the hangout and passes the Hangout URL to other potential participants. During the Hangout sessions the Hangout app sends information back to the server (using Ajax) on several events such as “onParticipantsAdded", "onParticipantsRemoved" etc.

I am trying to find out a way to notify the web app when the Hangout is over. The other events I mentioned (such as onParticipantsRemoved) will not work once the last participant leaves.

Currently I am sending a “heartbeat” from the hangout to the web app every few minutes, but I am wondering if there is a better way to know when the Hangout ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the hangout operates inside a window, you might be able to catch the onclose event for that window, but best practice is to rely on a heartbeat, as you've described.